# why my login is not working in my app in localhost with xampp

Tags: java, php, xml

I have created a app in which users can login by entering their email and password and the database for the activity was created from php my admin with xampp. The database name is user and table name is details. I test it by entering email and password which is in the database, but it doesn't make any reaction. Following I have included login.php, conn.php, login.java, backgroundWorker.java class.

### login.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1647a3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="2sp"
    android:paddingStart="2sp"
    tools:context="com.example.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.login"
    android:weightSum="1">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="7sp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
    android:paddingEnd="10sp"
    android:paddingStart="10sp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    tools:ignore="InefficientWeight"
    android:layout_weight="0.52" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_itst"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:paddingEnd="10sp"
    android:paddingStart="10sp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#cac6bc"
    android:textSize="32sp" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:paddingBottom="4sp"
        android:paddingEnd="16sp"
        android:paddingStart="16sp"
        android:text="@string/login_nw"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Et_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
    android:background="@drawable/passord"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/e_mail"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:paddingEnd="15sp"
    android:paddingStart="20sp"
    android:textColor="#d9d6d6"
    android:textColorHint="#292828" />


<EditText
        android:id="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:textColor="#d9d6d6"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/passord"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/pass_w"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:textColorHint="#292828" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/B_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/passord"
        android:text="@string/lgn"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/B_register"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/reg_now"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

### login.java

```
package com.example.sayuru.itstimetobeginsinanotherday;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


 public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

 EditText Etemail, Etpassword;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Etemail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Et_username);
    Etpassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Et_pssword);

 }

 public void onLogin(View view){
  String email=Etemail.getText().toString();
  String password=Etpassword.getText().toString();
  String type="login";
  BagroundWorker bagroundWorker=new BagroundWorker(this);
  bagroundWorker.execute(type, email, password);
 }
 }
```

### BackgroundWorker.java class

```
package com.example.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;



public class BagroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
 Context context;
 AlertDialog alertDialog;
 BagroundWorker(Context ctx){
    context=ctx;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type=params[0];
    String login_url="http:// 10.0.2.2/login.php";
    if (type.equals("login")){
        try {
            String email=params[1];
            String password=params[2];
            URL url=new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=
(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new 
OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data= URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-
8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-
8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                result +=line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("login status");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
 }
}
```

### conn.php to communicate with server

```
<?php 
$db_name = "user";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$server_name = "localhost";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, 
$mysql_password,$db_name);


?>
```

### login.php to login with server

```
<?php 
require "conn.php";
$user_email = $_POST["email"];
$user_pass = $_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry = "select * from details where email like '$user_email' and 
password 
like '$user_pass';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo "login success !!!!! Welcome user";
}
else {
echo "login not success";
}

?>
```

Comment: "... password like '$user_pass'" ? Seems like you store password in plain text. You should never do this! Use password_hash functions instead.

Comment: did you try with ip address, 127.0.0.1 in stead of 10.0.2.2 ?

Comment: ...not only are you storing the passwords in plain text, you're also _wide open_ to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. You're already using `mysqli` which has support for it, so that should be easy to implement.

Comment: _"it doesn't make any reaction"_ - What reaction are you expecting? All you're doing is echoing a string, regardless if it works or not. Suggestion: return a json object instead which you then handle accordingly in your app.

Comment: DON'T BUILD SQL QUERIES BY STRING CONCATENATION!  You WILL suffer an SQL injection attack sooner or later.  http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to enable input on httpURLConnection in the **BackgroundWorker.java** class (probably a typo):

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params{
    ...
    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
    ...
}
```

Always, try to handle responses in Json format and store an auth key for your logged-in users. Since i think this is just a try to get raw result from PHP, i don't describe more.

PHP recommendation:

1. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysqli
2. Store hashed passwords in database using **password_hash** or **bcrypt** (external function)
3. Use [prepared query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) instead of raw queries

**Update #1:**

**login.java**

```
package com.example.sayuru.itstimetobeginsinanotherday;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


 public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

     EditText Etemail, Etpassword;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Etemail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Et_username);
        Etpassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Et_pssword);
     }

     public void onLogin(View view){
         String email=Etemail.getText().toString();
         String password=Etpassword.getText().toString();
         String type="login";
         BagroundWorker bagroundWorker=new BagroundWorker(type, email, password);
         bagroundWorker.execute((Void) null);
     }
 }
```

**BackgroundWorker.java**

```
package com.example.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;



public class BagroundWorker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    String mType;
    String mEmail;
    String mPassword;
    BagroundWorker(String type, String email, String password){
        mType = type;
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String login_url="http:// 10.0.2.2/login.php";
        String result = "";
        if (mType.equals("login")) {
            try {
                URL url=new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=
(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                String data = "email=" + URLEncoder.encode(mEmail, "UTF-8") +
                              "password=" + URLEncoder.encode(mPassword, "UTF-8");
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new
                OutputStreamWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(data);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                int status = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        result += line;
                    }
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                result = false;
            } finally {
                if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("login status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

**conn.php** is just fine, but using PDO is preferred.

**login.php**

```
<?php 
require "conn.php";
$user_email = $_POST["email"];
$user_pass = $_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry = "select * from details where email like '$user_email' and 
password like '$user_pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "login success !!!!! Welcome user";
} else {
    echo "login not success";
}
```

This login.php will work as a sample, but never use unsecured code like this on a production server, ***it's very dangerous***.

Comment: Is this the solution? If not (since it's phrased as "first of all"), it should be written as a comment.

Comment: I think so, others are security recommendation.

Comment: **Do not recommend using sha1 for password hashing.** It's been knowingly insecure since 2005. In PHP, use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Never build your own hashing methods, since it will be insecure (it's a really complex issue).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sha1 is not insecure, its just too fast for Brute force attacks, you can handle it in many way to slow down the script response time. Additionaly, bcrypt is the most secure hashing method for passwords, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt

Comment: sha1 is broken. It's not just about the speed, but there are actually collision issues as well. https://shattered.io/. It's even deprecated in many systems/uses because of this. I didn't say that Bcrypt was insecure. The issue is that with Bcrypt, you still need to salt it and add some cost to it if you use it manually. Just creating a secure salt is a challenge enough, which is why you should use the built in and proven function `password_hash()` instead. That function is by default using Bcrypt, adds salt and you can easily configure the cost.

Comment: Creating secure hashes and salts are simply too complex for most people (definitely me included) and it's too easy to mess up. Use tools that many really smart people in that specific field have put together for you.

Comment: I am new to android and.So please answer me simply

Comment: can any one tell me how to make these changes to work it correctly

Comment: @spirit, according to the provided codes I make changes.login.java works fine but  BackgroundWorker.java not work correctly.It says cannot resolve symbol result and conn in  `} catch (Exception e) {
                result = false;
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            }

            return result;` and also `if (type.equals("login"))` is says cannot resolve symbol type.I think it may be mType

Comment: @TechlingdaTutorials sorry it was a typo bc i was copy/pasting some of the code from my own project. Its fixed now.

Comment: I tryied your solutions also.But it also not work then i change some parts in the code to start new activity `@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Navigation.class));
        //I add Context context to this code
    }`And it also not work.I tryind by using url as 192.1xx.x.xxx/login.php,127.0.0.1/login.php, 10.0.2.2/login.php.They also not work apart from that I tryied it in real device and android studio emulator.That also not work.   REST IN NEXT COMMENT

Comment: @spirit, REST FROM ABOVE COMMENT Please help me.Is this a problem of xampp or not.If yes help me to solve this. At last I request you to help me before November 2017 to get a working app.please help me

Comment: I dont think so but you can test your php result using Postman application.

Comment: @spirit, conn.php work fine but login.php said `<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: email in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php</b> on line
<b>3</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: password in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php</b> on line
<b>4</b>
<br />
login not success` when try in postman

Comment: Looks like you didnt post variables. You shoyld initiate variable before post with postman. Anyway your php is fine imo. Try some sample code from android tutorials and android github before starting your own code. Looks like you have some trouble in programming, not a special question about it. Try to learn before starting your own code.

Comment: @spirit, OK, what I want to change in the code to start a new activity.Please help me

Comment: Im so sorry bc this is not a training website and continuing this thread is in contrast with the site's regulation. this tutorial may help you https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/ in addition  you can simply google for codes and samples.

Comment: @spirit, thank you At last I ask from you can I use xampp without using wamp.

Comment: You shouldn't use xampp and wamp together, they're both web-servers.